# New Safari UserAgent - 6 digit number at the end

Tags: ios, iphone, web, safari

We are recording UserAgents for research and some time ago we started receiving these UserAgents from iPhone/iPads:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/600.7.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.7 Safari/600.7.12 (000767)"
```

There are multiple ones with just different 6 digit number at the end:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/600.7.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.7 Safari/600.7.12 (000764)"
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/600.7.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.7 Safari/600.7.12 (000765)"
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/600.7.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.7 Safari/600.7.12 (000825)"
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/600.7.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.7 Safari/600.7.12 (000826)"
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/600.7.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.7 Safari/600.7.12 (000790)"
```

They are all the same but that 6 digit number at the end is different. Does anyone know what does this 6 digit number at the end mean (for instance `(000790)` - scroll at the end of UserAgent strings above)? I can't find anything about it and it seems it is a recent addition from Apple. Also only `Safari/600.7.12` has it.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) - you must be getting traffic from a mobile app; the iOS version of a Cordova app appends this to the end of the user-agent string:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVViewController.m#L496

Had the same issue and a colleague tracked it down via a Cordova Slack.